# Merge [vault] tag into [sourcegear-vault]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The tag info for [vault](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vault/info) and [sourcegear-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sourcegear-vault/info) is identical.

Of the 20-ish questions that were tagged [vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vault), but not [sourcegear-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegear-vault), I've added the more-specific tag to less than half - those that were actually about SourceGear Vault.

The others referred to a variety of other products (from Oracle, Adobe, etc.), or to the concept of "secure vaults", etc..

Seems like [vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vault) should be removed as a choice for SourceGear Vault, to avoid ambiguity - whether a synomym or merge is appropriate, I don't know. Never proposed a tag change before. Better suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Probably not a synonym. Vault can mean a lot of things, as you have pointed out. The remaining questions seem easy enough to retag manually, although I'm not sure what will happen to the tag wiki in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what's the accepted best practice here. But "vault" alone seems too vague to be useful. It's just as valid for some of the other products.