# Please [vault] this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I went through the [vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vault) tag and replaced it with [ansible-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible-vault) as appropriate. The remaining questions seem to all be about [hashicorp-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashicorp-vault) (not an expert though), sometimes through a specific library such as [spring-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-vault). Can [vault] be merged into [hashicorp-vault]?

I assumed that any question mentioning Hashicorp doesn't need to be checked, and used a [search for the remaining questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvault%5D%20is%3Aq%20-hashicorp%20-%5Bhashicorp-vault%5D%20-%5Bhashicorp%5D%20-%5Bhashicorp-packer%5D%20-%5Bhashicorp-otto%5D%20-%5Bhashicorp-sentinel%5D%20-%5Bhashicorp-boundary%5D).

This question is part of a series:

- [Merge [vault] tag into [sourcegear-vault]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281215/6083675)
- [Merge candidates [vault] and [sourcegear-vault]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293539/6083675)
- [Close the [vault] forever?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377919/6083675)

Comment: There are still questions in there that are not about Hashicorp Vault. A "vault" is simply a nice catch-all name for managing credentials and certificates securely. It'll also describe Azure Key Vault for example.

Comment: @Gimby Azure's "vaults" have their own tags. I've retagged them as best I can.

Comment: *Lock the [vault]*? > Maybe burnination is the way to go here, as the tag is too ambiguous to be assigned as a synonym to any of the proposed tags.